# Bad module reference in GDAL -- QGIS 3.10.1

Tags: gdal, qgis-3

Trying to use GDAL with QGIS 3.10.1, I encounter the following error:

```
GDAL command:
python3 -m gdal_polygonize contextualWMSLegend=0&crs=EPSG:4326&dpiMode=7&featureCount=10&format=image/jpeg&layers=25&styles&url=https://maps.vcgi.vermont.gov/arcgis/services/VCGI_services/VCGI_BASEMAP_SP_v2/MapServer/WMSServer "C:/Users/Dan Grossman/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_53de98b33ff64a33948c3e46ee96da46/24da5c228f344e2a8c113d3c7a896890/OUTPUT.gpkg" -b 1 -f "GPKG" OUTPUT DN
GDAL command output:
C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS3~1.10\bin\python3.exe: No module named gdal_polygonize

'crs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[etc.]
```

`gdal_polygonize.py` is in the `QGIS 3.10 > apps > python37 > scripts` directory, so I have to assume that the module did not get include(ed). Other GDAL algorithms have the same problem. Beyond that, I'm stumped.

Comment: How do you launch gdal_polygonize? From some QGIS menu or what? Gdal_polygonize https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_polygonize.html is really a python  script and you can be run it as `python gdal_polygonize.py ...` from the command line. The wms stuff add the end of the line does not make sense in pure gdal_polygonize context.

Comment: I launched it from the QGIS Processing Toolbox.  I also tried running the same command through the Python console, with the same result. The input layer is on the WGS server referenced in the URL.  I think Python threw an exception long before that point in the script.

Comment: I would rather download image data from WCS with GDAL or with a hand written WCS GetCoverage request, save the response as GeoTIFF, and polygonize it. I suppose that QGIS is loading data in whatever resolution that fits best on the screen. I may be wrong, but with the other methods you can take the control on what really happens.